# limit results in foreach loop

Tags: php, loops, foreach, limit

The code below I have works fine but I wanted to check with you, the experts, to make sure I was using best practices.

I want to limit the loop results to 16. Does the code below seem like the best method?

Thanks,
Jeffrey

```
foreach ($flickr_set['items'] as $id => $photos) {
$ctr=0;  
         foreach ($photos as $photo) {
if($ctr>=16) break; else $ctr++; /* limits results to 16 */  
        echo '<a href="' . $photo['large'] . '" title="' . $photo['title'] . '" rel="flickr-set" ><img src="' . $photo['thumb'] . '" /></a>';
    }
}
```

Comment: how about adding a tag for what language that is?

Comment: Sorry, good call, this is only my second post here on stack overflow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution is fine, if you want a more structured solution which might be also more understandable, you can use [`array_slice`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-slice.php):

```
foreach ($flickr_set['items'] as $id => $photos) {
         foreach (array_slice($photos, 0, 16) as $photo) { 
        echo '<a href="' . $photo['large'] . '" title="' . $photo['title'] . '" rel="flickr-set" ><img src="' . $photo['thumb'] . '" /></a>';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine but..

I woudn't check if it is higher or equal i would only check if it equal like this:

```
if($ctr == 16)
```

Comment: Is this just personal preference or is it more a best practice?

Comment: @jeffreyd00 I would say more personal preference since you nerver expect it to be higher then 16! So i'm only comparing to equal 16

Comment: Thanks again. Both solutions work and are great. Appreciate the guidance.